# Why does the documentation for Cypher's exists predicate say it accepts a pattern when it doesn't?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The documentation for the `exists` predicate says it accepts a pattern or property.

This is a simple pattern, that returns a value

```
match (u:User) return u
```

This passes the same pattern to `exists` which then returns an error.

```
return exists((:User))
```

The error states

```
Invalid input ':': expected "NOT", an expression or an identifier
```

Which suggests that `exists` expects an expression or an identifier, but will choke if passed a basic pattern.

This however works, and returns `true`

```
return exists((:User)-->(:Account))
```

Which suggests that `exists` works for some patterns, but not for others, with the documentation giving no clue as to what we should expect to work and what won't.

What's going on? Am I misunderstanding something, or is the `exists` predicate badly implemented and/or documented?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do the similar workaround as here : https://twitter.com/graphileon/status/1471059683121184769?s=21